# XAMPP: Apache not running in windows 10

Tags: xampp

I have successfully installed XAMPP on windows 10 but Apache server is not working. It is showing error:

```
19:35:48  [Apache]  Apache Service detected with wrong path
19:35:48  [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
19:35:48  [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
19:35:48  [Apache]  Found Path: "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
19:35:48  [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Try the following
>
> select "Run as administrator"

[image]

> Click on the left button next to Apache

> Click on uninstall

[image]

> And that worked for me, hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Apache try to use port 80. but this port used by W3SVC service . so you just stop W3SVC service or change Apache port.

for stop W3SVC service:

1. windows key + R and type 'services.msc'
2. find from service list 'World Wide Web Publishing Service'
3. stop it and try again running Apache

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to run the cmd as administrator.

Please follow this steps:

```
On search write cmd it will appear right click and select run as administrator.

Now it will open the windows command line and write this:

net stop http

write S to select yes
```

...

Restart xampp and it will work now.